# C# - Count a specific word in richTextBox1 and send the result to label1

Tags: c#

I'm not sure, if this question is unique, but I couldn't find the answer that I was looking for.

I simply need a C# code that counts how many times a word appear in richTextBox1 and send the result to label1.

Example;
label1.text = how many times the word "house" appears in richTextBox1.

I know that I should try first but believe me I tried and I failed. I am new to this so I hope someone can show me.

Regards

Comment: If you've tried and failed, show us the non-working code so we can help you find your bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it using Regular Expressions as follows:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string searchstring = ....;
string input = richTextBox1.Text;
int count = Regex.Matches(input, searchstring, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;

label1.Text = count.ToString();
```

Do please note, that the code above only works for one single word containing the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.

---

**EDIT No.1:** If you want to match any exact sequence, you could use the following method:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string searchstring = ....;
string input = richTextBox1.Text;

searchstring = Regex.Escape(searchstring);

int count = Regex.Matches(input, searchstring, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;

label1.Text = count.ToString();
```

The method above should match any UTF-16 character sequence and count it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Unknown6656 for the help.

I did add [using System.Text.RegularExpressions;] at the right place on the top and the rest of the code under
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Is this right? I couldn't make it to work complete. I do get a "0" on label1. Any idea what I did wrong? Maybe you could simply add a search word ''apple'' in the C# code under  private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) so I can see if I do anything wrong. And again thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @alt2090: Yes, Sir - you did insert the snippet at the correct places inside your code. I will review my code snippet and look for any errors and notify you after I have found your issue :)

Comment: @alt2090: I tested my code and it worked without any issues. Do you have special characters, line breaks (such as `\n`, `\r`) or spaces etc. in your search string? Or is your code somehow skipping over the upper/lower case of your search string?

Comment: private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchstring = "\n verdi";
            string input = richTextBox1.Text;

            input = string.Join("", input.Select(c => "\\u" + ((ushort)c).ToString("x4")));
            int count = Regex.Matches(input, searchstring).Count;
            label5.Text = count.ToString();
        }

Comment: @alt2090: I found my mistake and I changed my code accordingly. Please [click here to see my edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34561025/revisions).

Comment: @alt2090: Do please remember to close this question (by ticking the correct answer with the green tick-mark), if this solved your issue